# Quiz with a mix of input field type (radio, text and checkbox) using Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need to build a quiz with a mix of different type of questions.
Some will be a checkbox and some will be fill in the blanks like the example below:

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="checbox-q">
<span>What is an animal?<?span>
<input type="checkbox" id="q1-a1" value="1">
<label>Dog</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="q1-a2" value="2">
<label>Tiger</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="q1-a3" value="3">
<label>Flower</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="q1-a4" value="4">
<label>Cat</label>
</div>

<div class="fillBlanks-q">
<span>Apples can be in the colour <input type="text" id="q2-a1"> and <input type="text" id="q2-a2">.</span>
</div>

<div class="list-q">
<span>List 3 types of Grapes<?span>
<ol>
<li><input type="text" id="q3-a1"></li>
<li><input type="text" id="q3-a1"></li>
<li><input type="text" id="q3-a1"></li>
</ol>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Using Jquery, how do I now display the score in percentage?
I'm a bit new to JavaScript(Jquery) and I know that to use only checkbox I can use arrays but how would that work when also input texts?

Really appreciate some help.
Thank you

Comment: what are you asking for? validating the input values? collecting the results of the validations? calculation of a percentage?

Comment: Hi. I'm looking for a collection of results and show it in percentage.

Comment: create all inputs into a var, check if the input is the same as the correct answer and add points to a point system if yes?

Comment: Thank you. I kind of understand what you are saying but would you mind sharing an example, please?